# Rails form - select field, display fullname but submit ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I am trying to add an association between a group and an employee through a membership controller. In the form for this association I want two strings attributes to be displayed but an ID to be submitted.

My membership controller needs a group_id and an employee_id for the create action :

```
def create
    @employee = Employee.find(params[:employee_id])
    @membership = @employee.memberships.build(group_id: params[:group_id])
    if @membership.save
      flash[:notice] = "Collaborateur ajouté au groupe."
      redirect_to groups_url
    else
      flash[:error] = "Erreur lors de l'ajout du collaborateur."
      redirect_to groups_url
    end
  end
```

From the `groups/show.html.erb` page I have a `link_to` to membership#new action which pass the `group_id` as parameter and render the new membership form. In that form I have a select field in which I want to display `employee.lastname` and `employee.firstname` but submitting the `id` of the selected employee instead of the displayed value.

**Form**

```
<%= form_for(@membership, :html => {class: 'form-horizontal'}) do |f| %>

    <div class="box-body">
      <%= f.hidden_field :group_id, value: params[:group_id] %>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :employee_id, class: 'col-sm-3 control-label' %>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <%= f.select(:employee_id, Employee.all.map{|e| [e.fullname, e.id]},
          {prompt: 'Selectionner'}, { class: 'form-control' } ) %>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="box-footer">
      <%= f.submit "Valider", class: "btn btn-primary pull-right" %>
    </div>
```

I have 2 issues with that form :

First, the `fullname` method is not working, in result the form can't be displayed and the server print :

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `fullname' for
 #<Employee:0x007fc458e61738>)
```

The `fullname` method is defined in the EmployeesController

```
def fullname
    @employee = Employee.find(params[:id])
    fullname = "#{@employee.firstname} #{@employee.lastname}"
  end
```

Second, I have try the same syntax and replace the `fullname` method with the `lastname` attribute, then the form is displayed but when submitting a record not found error is raised :

```
Started POST "/memberships" for ::1 at 2017-05-16 10:55:52 +0200
Processing by MembershipsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"1gJ5VQjNemlEC/8H2O1eutJtyHPArqDMrT8RXZ9rNMp2PUu/ux1SzIgbzCFsL3Jc4mOJ+aZvX7RSwVUIJoruow==", "membership"=>{"group_id"=>"1", "employee_id"=>"4"}, "commit"=>"Valider"}
  Employee Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "employees".* FROM "employees" WHERE "employees"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", nil], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 6ms (ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)



ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Employee with 'id'=)
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your First error
1. create a `full_name` method in `Employee` model it self. like

```
def full_name
  self.lastname + self.firstname
end
```

so you can directly access `full_name` where ever you want

ex:

```
@employee = Employee.find(params[:employee_id])
@full_name = @employee.full_name
```

2. Second error

in your controller

change `params[:group_id]` and `params[:employee_id]` to `params[:membership][:employee_id]` and `params[:membership][:group_id]`.

like

```
def create
    @employee = Employee.find(params[:membership][:employee_id])
    @membership = @employee.memberships.build(group_id: params[:membership][:group_id])
    if @membership.save
      flash[:notice] = "Collaborateur ajouté au groupe."
      redirect_to groups_url
    else
      flash[:error] = "Erreur lors de l'ajout du collaborateur."
      redirect_to groups_url
    end
  end
```

Comment: Welcome :) @Arnaud

Answer (score 1):

To address the first issue: you are calling the `#fullname` method on instances of your `Employee model`, having the method in your controller does nothing, you will need to move it into the model and change it to something like:

```
def fullname
  "#{firstname} #{lastname}"
end
```

The second issue is, about the way the parameters are set. The employee_id is sent to the controller as part of the form, if you look at the parameters being sent in your request we can see:

```
"membership"=>{"group_id"=>"1", "employee_id"=>"4"}
```

so the employee_id is being correctly sent, however because it is part of the form for a membership model, it get sent as part of membership models parameters, in `params[:membership][:employee_id]`, but you are trying to access it with `params[:employee_id]`

However because you are already sending the group_id and employee_id as parameters to your controller action, you do not need to create an instance of employee and build from it, the id is already being set, so you can change:

```
def create
  @employee = Employee.find(params[:employee_id])
  @membership = @employee.memberships.build(group_id: params[:group_id])
  ....
end
```

to:

```
def create
  Membership.save(membership_params)
  ...
end

private

def membership_params
  params.require(:membership).permit(:group_id, :employee_id)
end
```

Comment: @Arnaud I have added further to my answer to help you simplify what you are doing in the controller, I hoep it can help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've try to do your way but I still get the same error RecordNotFound for employee 'id=' ... The answer of Narasimha Reddy above works by accessing params[:membership][:employee_id] instead of just params[:employee_id]

Comment: @Arnaud Yes, but in Rails it is bad practice to use the forms parameters for that purpose, the form parameters are to set the attributes of the model, and you should use StrongParameters to do that, like in the membership_params method I showed above, you do not need to make an `@employee` instance variable to save your membership record, it is a useless command and is increasing your SQL hits for no reason. please see here on how to use StrongParameters: http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html

Comment: I understand that using string parameters is a good practice and so don't do is bad... To build my current application I've followed the Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial and build some model + form using strong parameters. In this case of a join model I just don't achieve to make it working. I need more practice to understand the way things are called through models and controllers and to understand variables scopes. I'll try to refactor my code to fit the use of strong parameters, and if you know good resources treating of variable scope / call in rails let me know :)